# Raspberry Pi VPN Server for gaming

Tags: networking

Is it a good idea to use a Pi as a vpn server for playing online games like dota 2 and league of legends. Can it handle the traffic/load? I'm living on campus at the moment and most online games ports are blocked. I'm planning to set it up at a friend of mine who lives off campus. His connection has good peering with the campus ISP.

Comment: Not sure about Raspberry pi servers but there are others which provides such servers, I use VPN for gaming, i play dota 2. So for that i use a vpn client.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but the speeds are not the best ( You could use an old Desktop and get much better performance ).

[Here](http://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2012/08/raspberry-pi-use-as-vpn-server.html) is the link to Stuff about="Code" blog.